# How do I re-install Windows 10 after upgrade

Tags: windows-10

I have Windows 10, as I upgraded from Windows 7

Everything works fine, but it's quite possible I will need to re-install the OS at a later date.

When I upgraded, I was not provided with a new key.

When I visit http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10 I get an a.exe which gives me 2 options. Upgrade or create installation for a new PC. Neither is what I want as the page cited suggests I can create an ISO for this PC.

If I were to reformat my PC today, how can I re-install Windows 10 as I have no key and no ISO?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007, thanks for the link, but that link is about W10 insider. Do you know if the same principal applies? As such, I don't believe this is a dupe question!

Comment: Yup, hence why I pointed you towards it. ;)  Additionally, from my understanding, is that now that Threshold 2 was released, if you use the ISO form via the MediaCreator from MS, You can now use your Windows 7 key to install from scratch. But again, as the dupes points out,, if you've already upgraded to 10 on that computer, reinstalling it should "just work", since MS has it's activation recorded.

Answer (score -2):

The key is the only part of the operating system that needs to be saved...
Anything else is are your personal files that have nothing to do with the os.

For one key viewer:(many more out in the web)

http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/product_cd_key_viewer.html

Find your key,
Write down your key ON PAPER - stick it with some tape UNDER your computer.

1. You wont have to remember where it is.
2. You will have it if your phone goes to crap, or gets hacked.
3. If you could rely on your pc for it - you wouldn't be copying it on to paper.

ALT:

Make an install cd and write the key on it.

... ISO you can grab anywhere, if whatever Microsoft page you are stuck on wont give it to you. People who are out in foreign countries often grab them from local torrents because they don't want to wait extensive download times from MS servers. Its completely legal. The legality part is about the key, the install you can get anywhere, obviously don't get it from too shady places :)

In any event you should have the key onhand as any misstep with your install and loss of key puts you through having to recover that key via microsoft, which can get tedious.